# JPanel changes shape/position within JFrame when JButton is pressed. Why?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Basically, I have added a JPanel to a JFrame, and whenever I press the button within the JPanel (which changes the visibility of a component within the JPanel), the size of the JPanel and the location of the components change. I cant for the life of me figure out why this problem is occurring. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Google Searches

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

private JFrame window;
private JPanel loginPanel;
private JButton loginButton;
private JTextField usernameField;
private JPasswordField passwordField;
private JLabel usernameLabel, passwordLabel, errorMessage;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main program = new Main();
}

public Main() {
    createWindow();
    runProgram();
}

private void createWindow() {

    window = new JFrame("Dentist Program");
    window.setSize(1450, 900);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    loginPanel = new JPanel();
    loginPanel.setSize(300, 400);
    loginPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

    usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username");
    usernameLabel.setSize(125, 20);
    usernameLabel.setLocation(loginPanel.getWidth()/2 - usernameLabel.getWidth()/2, 100);

    usernameField = new JTextField();
    usernameField.setSize(125, 25);
    usernameField.setLocation(loginPanel.getWidth()/2 - usernameField.getWidth()/2, usernameLabel.getY() + usernameLabel.getHeight());

    passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    passwordLabel.setSize(125, 20);
    passwordLabel.setLocation(loginPanel.getWidth()/2 - passwordLabel.getWidth()/2, usernameField.getY() + usernameField.getHeight() + 10);

    passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    passwordField.setSize(125, 25);
    passwordField.setLocation(loginPanel.getWidth()/2 - passwordField.getWidth()/2, passwordLabel.getY() + passwordLabel.getHeight());

    loginButton = new JButton("Log In");
    loginButton.setSize(80, 25);
    loginButton.setLocation(passwordField.getX(), passwordField.getY() + passwordField.getHeight() + 15);
    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                errorMessage.setText("");
                loginPanel.repaint();
            }
            });

    errorMessage = new JLabel("Username and/or password is incorrect");
    errorMessage.setSize(250, 25);
    errorMessage.setLocation(loginPanel.getWidth()/2 - errorMessage.getWidth()/2, loginButton.getY() + loginButton.getHeight() + 25);
    errorMessage.setForeground(Color.RED);

    loginPanel.add(usernameLabel);
    loginPanel.add(usernameField);
    loginPanel.add(passwordLabel);
    loginPanel.add(passwordField);
    loginPanel.add(loginButton);
    loginPanel.add(errorMessage);

    window.getContentPane().add(loginPanel);
    window.repaint();

}

private void runProgram() {

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your UI changes is because the look that you think is correct (the initial look) is actually wrong, and the resized version is the "correct" version.

Typically, you'd call `pack()` after adding components to a container, which tries to display the contents of that container at their preferred sizes. To see the correct UI before and after the button press, following your call to `repaint()`, add:

```
window.pack();
```

You may think that looks terrible (which it does) but it's exactly what your code is asking for, and is therefore the "correct" version.

Take note that you are trying to set sizes with explicit calls to `setSize()`, which is a bad practice in Swing. At most, you should be setting preferred sizes and letting the layout manager handle the details. When you try to micromanage component sizes and locations, you can often make it look good on one platform, but irredeemably bad on others. Remember that Java is supposed to be the "write once, run anywhere" language.

When you want more control over your layout, you should explicitly specify and use a layout manager, rather than just accepting the default layout. In almost every non-trivial UI, [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) is your best bet.

Finally, you don't need to explicitly call `repaint()` on your UI when something changes. Typically, you'd call `paint()` and `repaint()` when you are working with graphics. Let Swing handle the painting automatically.

Comment: Thank you not only for answering my questions, but making me aware of better practices as well!

Comment: @WesleyBrandt Glad to be of service.